# Median Function in C Math Library?

Tags: c

Is there any math function in C library to calculate MEDIAN of 'n' numbers?

Comment: [Here you go](http://ndevilla.free.fr/median/median/index.html).

Answer (score 9):

**Conventional Method:** (not recommended if you are working on image processing)

```
/* median through qsort example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ELEMENTS 6

int values[] = { 40, 10, 100, 90, 20, 25 };

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main ()
{
  int n;
  qsort (values, ELEMENTS, sizeof(int), compare);
  for (n=0; n<ELEMENTS; n++)
  {   printf ("%d ",values[n]); }
  printf ("median=%d ",values[ELEMENTS/2]);
  return 0;
}
```

However, are two functions to calculate median the fastest way without sorting the array of candidates. The following are at least 600% faster than conventional ways to calculate median. Unfortunately they are not a part of C standard Library or C++ STL.

**Faster Methods:**

```
//===================== Method 1: =============================================
//Algorithm from N. Wirth’s book Algorithms + data structures = programs of 1976    

typedef int_fast16_t elem_type ;

#ifndef ELEM_SWAP(a,b)
#define ELEM_SWAP(a,b) { register elem_type t=(a);(a)=(b);(b)=t; }

elem_type kth_smallest(elem_type a[], uint16_t n, uint16_t k)
{
    uint64_t i,j,l,m ;
    elem_type x ;
    l=0 ; m=n-1 ;
    while (l<m) {
    x=a[k] ;
    i=l ;
    j=m ;
    do {
    while (a[i]<x) i++ ;
    while (x<a[j]) j-- ;
    if (i<=j) {
    ELEM_SWAP(a[i],a[j]) ;
    i++ ; j-- ;
    }
    } while (i<=j) ;
    if (j<k) l=i ;
    if (k<i) m=j ;
    }
    return a[k] ;
}

    #define wirth_median(a,n) kth_smallest(a,n,(((n)&1)?((n)/2):(((n)/2)-1)))

//===================== Method 2: =============================================
//This is the faster median determination method.
//Algorithm from Numerical recipes in C of 1992

elem_type quick_select_median(elem_type arr[], uint16_t n)
{
    uint16_t low, high ;
    uint16_t median;
    uint16_t middle, ll, hh;
    low = 0 ; high = n-1 ; median = (low + high) / 2;
    for (;;) {
    if (high <= low) /* One element only */
    return arr[median] ;
    if (high == low + 1) { /* Two elements only */
    if (arr[low] > arr[high])
    ELEM_SWAP(arr[low], arr[high]) ;
    return arr[median] ;
    }
    /* Find median of low, middle and high items; swap into position low */
    middle = (low + high) / 2;
    if (arr[middle] > arr[high])
    ELEM_SWAP(arr[middle], arr[high]) ;
    if (arr[low] > arr[high])
    ELEM_SWAP(arr[low], arr[high]) ;
    if (arr[middle] > arr[low])
    ELEM_SWAP(arr[middle], arr[low]) ;
    /* Swap low item (now in position middle) into position (low+1) */
    ELEM_SWAP(arr[middle], arr[low+1]) ;
    /* Nibble from each end towards middle, swapping items when stuck */
    ll = low + 1;
    hh = high;
    for (;;) {
    do ll++; while (arr[low] > arr[ll]) ;
    do hh--; while (arr[hh] > arr[low]) ;
    if (hh < ll)
    break;
    ELEM_SWAP(arr[ll], arr[hh]) ;
    }
    /* Swap middle item (in position low) back into correct position */
    ELEM_SWAP(arr[low], arr[hh]) ;
    /* Re-set active partition */
    if (hh <= median)
    low = ll;
    if (hh >= median)
    high = hh - 1;
    }
    return arr[median] ;
}
#endif
```

In C++ I make these **templated functions** and if the numbers are increasing or decreasing (one direction) for such functions use **int8_fast_t; int16_fast_t; int32_fast_t; int64_fast_t; uint8_fast_t; uint16_fast_t; types instead of regular [stdint.h] types (e.g. uint16_t; uint32_t, etc)**

Comment: The code above will fail in case of even numbers of elements (It won't take the mean of the 2 middle elements).

Answer (score 5):

To compute the median using the standard C library, use the standard library function `qsort()` and then take the middle element.  If the array is `a` and has `n` elements, then:

```
qsort(a, n, sizeof(a[0]), compare);
return a[n/2];
```

You have to write your own `compare` function which will depend on the type of an array element.  For details consult the man page for `qsort` or look it up in the index of Kernighan and Ritchie.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such function in the standard C library.

However, you can implement one (or surely find code online). An efficient O(n) algorithm for finding a median is called "selection algorithm" and is related to quicksort. Read all about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no median function in the standard C library.

Answer (score 1):

What about `std::nth_element`? If I'm correctly understanding the nature of the median, this would give you one for odd number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

to get the median you can sort the array of numbers and take:

1) in case when number of items is odd - the number in the middle

2) in case when number of items is even - the average of two numbers in the middle

Comment: @Eli: simplicity often trumps efficiency and I have a gut feeling that this is what OP wants

Comment: @catwalk: fair enough, but then it would be prudent to explicitly specify in your answer that it's the simple, not the efficient solution